# Tags not showing up while querying an ADX table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

If I fire `.show table <TableName> extents` I do see the list of extents with tags. But if I try to list those tags along with the table data I get blank, so the following query returns blank tags:-

```
<TableName> | extend tags=extent_tags()
```

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you querying the table *directly*, or after applying some operators/functions on the raw data? (perhaps, hidden by a function that shares the same name as the table, and therefore 'hides' it)

as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extenttagsfunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer) mention:

> Applying this function to calculated data which is not attached to a data shard returns an empty value

Comment: I am applying extend right on top of the raw data. I verified with various different tables -- for none of the tables I am able to see tags when I apply extend operator to see tags just using the command I have specified in my post -- nothing complex. But in all the cases it's showing blank. But when tags still show up with the show table command.

Comment: we discussed this offline and found out that the query was actually `T | take 100 | project extent_tags()` - which aligns with what's written in the docs. had it been `T | project extent_tags | take 100` - it would have worked

Comment: another case @Dhiraj had was with a function that shares the same name as the function (so the function hides the table). that can be 'bypass'ed by using the `table()` function, e.g.: `table("TableName") | project extent_tags()`